# Secondary monitor does not list its native resolution

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup with both of them connected to the GPU: the main one via HDMI to DVI and the secondary one via VGA to HDMI.

Lately I've been having this issue where the main monitor flashes black for a second, then starts working again and Windows displays an error about the driver failing.

So I uninstalled the GPU drivers completely using Display Driver Uninstaller and installed it again. Now instead of one problem I have two problems:

The driver failing error still happens but now my secondary monitor resolution is messed up. It should be 1440x900 but it is not even listed anymore. What can I do?